# How to mount a virtual hard drive to an existing virtual image?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, hard-drive

I need help expanding my hard drive.
I created a virtual image to run Ubuntu on an Oracle VM (fixed 8Gbs). I have since created a second virtual hard drive that will expand as needed. I want to install more software and allow the second hard drive take some of the load. My problem is in the mounting I believe. (i am new to linux)

Thus far i have partitioned the second drive and mounted it to /media/mynewdrive
But it just sits there. I need to move some programs over to the second drive. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I know the command line way much better - so here we go using command line and your favourite text editor only:

Open up the terminal of your choice (ex. gnome-terminal) and check where your data sits

`sudo du -xh --max-depth=1 /`

For simplicity I recommend to mount the new partition under a first level directory.

Think about which data you want to put on the new partition. Common choices are `/home` if you have lots of Movies/Fotos/VirtualDiskImages/... :), or `/usr` if you want to install more software from your distribution, `/var` if you run a for example a mail server, `/opt` if you use lots of third party software there / ...

Be sure you formatted your partition with a linux file system (I recommend ext4).

You can check this typing `mount` which gives you all mounted file systems including file system and mount options you may want to copy and paste later to `/etc/fstab`

The format is:

`<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>`

So first we copy a hole first level folder to the new partition and configure `/etc/fstab` (file system table) and test if everything is done right. Then we remove the data from old partition. I assume you want to move `/home` Partition so replace this if you choose other.

`sudo cp -aT /home /media/mynewdrive`

If `mynewdrive` was empty `/home` and `/media/mynewdrive` contain the same data. Probably there is an additional `lost+found` folder in `mynewdrive` which was created during formatting which you can ignore.

Now add a line to `/etc/fstab` using `<youreditor>`. Replace this with for example with `gedit`.

`sudo <youreditor> /etc/fstab`

The line you add will look like this

`<file system> /home   <type>  <options> 0 2`

You have to replace `<options>` simply with `defaults` or with options you got from `mount` but without brackets and don't use `noauto` cause this prevents from mounting automatically while system boot. Be sure to have spaces and/or tabs between entries and commas (and no spaces or tabs) between options. Save and close.

Now you check if everything worked an you can mount the new partition to the right folder:

`sudo mount /home`

It worked if you get no output. Then you can see it using again `mount`. Check if your data are in place:

`sudo du -hs /home` should show the same size as on first run above.

Now remove the original data on root partition:

`sudo umount /home`

**Only do next step if everything went fine until here and you checked new partition is not mounted at `/home`:**

`sudo rm -r /home && sudo mkdir /home`

now you can mount it again:

`sudo mount /home`

and `umount` from `/media`

`sudo umount /media/mynewdrive` (which you could have done at any point ;) )

And always do final test: *reboot*